# Prove $A$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1], Af(x) = f(x)/x$ with domain $D(A) = ${$f \in C[0,1]: \exists \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)/x$}.

Prove that $A$ is closed.

I know that A linear operator $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is closed provided whenever {$x_n$} $\rightarrow x_0$ and $T(x_n) \rightarrow y_0$ then $T(x_0) = y_0$, but I'm not really sure how to proceed.  I see a theorem that says a linear operator between Banach spaces is continuous iff its closed, but I'm not really sure how to apply that here or if I even should

Comment: I think you might have a bit of a mistake here: $A$ looks like an *operator* not a *set*, so it doesn't make sense to talk about $x \in A$. Do you know the definition of a closed operator?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. Are you asking if $D(A)$ is closed or if $A$ is a closed operator?

Comment: @user296602 oops.  It's not in my notes but I've found online that it's "A linear operator $A : D(A) \rightarrow H$ is closed if for any
sequence of vectors $f_n \in D(A)$ such that, as $n \rightarrow \infty, f_n \rightarrow f$ and $Af_n \rightarrow g$, it follows that
$f \in D(A)$ and $Af = g$"

Comment: @copper.hat A is a closed operator

Comment: if $f(x)=\sqrt x$, ${{{nx}f(1/n)}\over x}=\sqrt n$, $f_n$ does not converge towards $f$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide how does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f_n \to f$, $A f_n \to g$, we want to show that $Af = g$.

The idea is note that if we let $\gamma(x) = x g(x)$, then $A \gamma = g$ and all we need to do is to show that $f_n \to \gamma$.

Since $Af_n \to g$, for any $\epsilon>0$ then there is some $N$ such that  $|{f_n(x)\over x} - {g(x)}| \le \epsilon$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $n \ge N$. 
Hence $|f_n(x)-xg(x)| \le \epsilon|x| \le \epsilon$. In particular, $\|f_n-\gamma\| \to 0$, where $\gamma(x) = x g(x)$.

Hence $f= \gamma$ and so $A$ is closed.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you, but I'm kind of confused. What does showing that $D(A)$ is not closed accomplish?  I'm just looking at the definition of closed operator so I may be missing out on a lot

Comment: @JohnSmith: I added an answer.

Comment: thanks.  In the last inequality how do you get that $|x|\leq 1$?

Comment: The domain of functions in $C[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks